# Unable to unlink (delete) file from server after upload through Dropbox API

Tags: php, laravel, upload, dropbox

When I do upload file through the Dropbox API (Server->Dropbox), I want to delete the current file from the server. Unfortunately gives me the following error:

```
unlink(path_to_file/file_name.jpg): Resource temporarily unavailable
```

I'm using Laravel 5.5 (I believe it is not related but just in case.)
I put sleep(), made some delays only for testing, but still doesn't work. Somehow something hold the file and it is unable to be deleted after I upload it, even after parsing the response from Dropbox that the file is uploaded correctly.

How to free the file to be able to be deleted?

Comment: Show us the `path_to_file` is it a temporary directory?

Comment: No path to file is real directory.
If I use Unlink without uploading. Unlink works properly and delete file, folder or whatever I need. But if the file has been used for uploading (just before the deleting), gives the error. Have to unset it somehow, but even when I use unset() still gives the error. Somehow in the background the file continues to be used from something...

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.
Because I'm using dropbox sdk for Laravel:
https://github.com/kunalvarma05/dropbox-php-sdk/wiki/Upload-and-Download-Files

I found how to stop the stream (to free the file). After upload have to close with this method:

```
$dropboxFile = new DropboxFile($file_path);
$file = $dropbox->upload($dropboxFile, $path_to_upload_parent.$file, ['autorename' => true]);
$dropboxFile->close();
```

Comment: Nice find! You are using Laravel so use https://github.com/spatie/flysystem-dropbox instead of pure dopbox-php-sdk :) Good luck.